# Haproxy map: Mapping 1 ID to multiple rows

Tags: authentication, dictionary, haproxy

I am trying to achieve a form of authentication in HAProxy where 1 authentication ID can be mapped to multiple data ID's which pretty much restrict data access to my Api's when in the user is calling them.  I want to do this in a map file since these ID's are going to change very frequently. So writing individual rules isn't plausible.

So in theory I want to do this:

user X calls endpoint with data ID 123. User is given access.

user X calls endpoint with data ID 456. User is given access.

user y calls endpoint with data ID 123. User is denied access.

Example map file:
Left coloumn is ID  and right is DataID

- X 123
- X 456
- X 789
- Y 121
- Y 111
- Z 123

Is this doable? If not, what would be a good alternative to mimic this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key (left column) should be unique in your case.
That said, this is perfectly doable with a map file like the one below:

```
X-123  allow
X-456  allow
X-789  allow
Y-121  allow
Y-111  allow
Z-123  allow
```

First, you must concatenate both username and data-id in a temporary HTTP header, then you use it like:

```
http-request set-header X-my-internal-key %[req.hdr(Username)]-%[req.hr(myendpoint_id)]
http-request deny unless { req.hdr(X-my-internal-key),map(/path/to/mapfile.map) -m found }
```

Baptiste

Comment: This is a great approach, thank you very much for this awesome answer!